# SAPUI5 - FilterBar - setVisible not working

Tags: filter, sapui5, visible, typeerror

I'm using `sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar` Control on a project. Everything works fine, except when I try to hide this Control.

```js
var oFilterBar = new sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar("filterBar",{
    reset: oController.handleOnReset,
    search: oController.handleOnSearch,
    showRestoreOnFB: true,
    showClearOnFB: true,
    showRestoreButton: true,
    showClearButton: true,
    ...
    });
oFilterBar.setVisible(false);
```

I'm getting the following error:
`Uncaught TypeError: oFilterBar.setVisible is not a function`

Since this property is being inherited from sap.ui.core.Control class, this should work and I think it has nothing to do with versions either (I'm using 1.24).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has something to do with the version.

In SAPUI5 1.28[[1]](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#releasenotes.html) the property `visible` was moved to `sap.ui.core.Control` so any Control extending it would have this property as well.

If you are using an earlier version only Control that implement this property themselves can be made invisible.

---

You could however extend the control you are using to include this property:

```js
sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBar.extend("my.FilterBar", {
    metadata: {
        properties: {
            visible: {
                type: "boolean",
                group: "Appearance"
            }
        }
    },
    renderer: function (oRm, oControl) {
        if (oControl.getVisible()) {
            sap.ui.comp.filterbar.FilterBarRenderer.render(oRm, oControl);
        } else {
            // Handle invisibility
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Not doing anything in the renderer in case of not visible works fine. It just leads to the parent being invalidated when something changes in the control.

Comment: Yes, extend was going to be my next approach... or maybe I should ask for an upgrade on ui5 version :) Thanks!

Comment: You should definitively upgrade. 1.24 is out of maintenance. 1.30 will be out soon.